# If $\rho(g):V\to V$ is $G$-linear for every $\rho$, then $g$ is in the center of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $\rho: G\to GL(V)$ be a representation, Fulton and Harris (page 8, bottom) claim that if $\rho(g):V\to V$ is $G$-linear for every $\rho$ implies that $g$ is in the center of $G$ (the other direction is easy).

I wonder how to prove this result. It seems that it is very sophisticated. "For every $\rho$" is very hard to use.

Comment: Here is a sketch to follow: Show that this implies that $g$ acts as a scalar on any irreducible. Extend this to see that it acts as a diagonal matrix on any representation. Use this to show that the action of $g$ commutes with the action of any other element. Consider the regular representation to conclude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see that $g$ must be central, we can consider the regular representation $(R_G, \rho)$ of $G$, which is the permutation representation associated to the action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication (see page 5, end of section 1.1):
The representation $R_G$ has a basis $\{ e_h \mid h \in G \}$, on which the action of $G$ on $R_G$ is given by
$$
    \rho(h')(e_h)
  = h'.e_h
  = e_{h'h}
  \qquad
  \text{for all $h', h \in G$}.
$$
For $\rho(g)$ to be $G$-linear we need that
$$
  h.\rho(g)(v) = \rho(g)(h.v)
  \qquad
  \text{for all $h \in G$, $v \in R_G$}.
$$
By setting $v = e_1$ (where $1$ is the unit of $G$) we get that
$$
    e_{hg}
  = e_{gh}
  \qquad
  \text{for all $h \in G$},
$$
and therefore that $hg = gh$ for all $h \in G$.

---

Note that $g \in G$ is central if and only if the left multiplication $G \to G$, $h \mapsto gh$ is $G$-equivariant, where $G$ acts on itself by left multiplication.
The above can be understood as a linearization of this argument.
You will see this kind of linearization again in section 3.4, where the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$ will be introduced.